# How to deduplicate Core Data entity records when using CloudKit?

Tags: core-data, cloudkit

Since unique constraint is not something available when using CloudKit and storing some entities inside `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` would cause duplicated records after the data is synced across multiple devices.

Is there any existing best practice to deduplicate Core Data entity records stored on CloudKit?

---

I store the app's current user object in Core Data with iCloud user record ID as the unique identifier; however, after the entry got synced to other devices, multiple users appear under the `User` SQLite data.

```swift
    func getLocalUser() -> User? {
        /// Try to fetch the only local user
        let idMixpanel = DCMixpanel.shared.distinctId
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<User> = User.fetchRequest()
        let userPredicate = NSPredicate(
            format: "%K = %@",
            #keyPath(User.idMixpanel),
            idMixpanel
        )

        fetchRequest.predicate = userPredicate

        let userList = try? container.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

        if let user = userList?.first {
            if user.idCloudKit == nil {
                /// This method is async and the ID is not available immediately after function invocation
                setupCloudKitUserID()
            }
            return user
        }

        /// Create a new local user if no user found with local ID
        let userLocalNew = User(context: container.viewContext)

        userLocalNew.idMixpanel = DCMixpanel.shared.distinctId


        saveContext()

        return userLocalNew
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to create a `mergeLocalUser` method:

```swift
private func mergeLocalUser() -> User? {
    /// (1) Fetch all users
    /// (2) Merge users if there are more than one user in the local database
    /// (3) Implement custom user properties merging logic
    /// (4) Delete all user instances and re-create a new user
        
    return newUserInstance
}
```